# C++ std::transform side effect

Tags: c++, stl

I've implementation of UnaryOperation like this

```
struct Converter
{
    Converter( std::size_t value ):
        value_( value ), i_( 0 )
    {}
    std::string operator() ( const std::string& word )
    {
        return ( value_ & ( 1 << i_++ ) ) ?
            word:
            std::string( word.size(), ' ' );
    }
    std::size_t value_;
    std::size_t i_;
};
```

And I use it like

```
std::vector v;
// initialization of v  
std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(),
                std::back_inserter( result ),
                Converter( data ) );
```

My **question** is can I rely on my assumption that algorithm will call my 'Converter operator ()' in the order that 'Converter::i_' will correspond to number of element in 'v'.

Please quote the standard in case I can't rely on the order or put the stl-like solution that avoid possible problem if any.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I am aware of "no Side effect" requirements in the standard for the transform algorithm. I can't find what is exactly "side effect" for functors in the same standard.

Maybe there is some good-looking-boost-like solution for this task?

Comment: actually, the note about the side-effect doesn't appear anymore in the current draft. but instead, it says that algorithms are free to copy their function objects around unless otherwise stated. so i think "side effects" there mean to modify members of the function object.

Comment: As of C++11, the rule has changed: "_`unary_op` and `binary_op` must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, or modify any elements of the ranges involved." But I would still presume that other side effects are undesirable if the algorithm can be parallelised (esp. by execution policy).

Comment: Noting that a bounty has been placed seeking answers post C++11 -  C++17 introduces an overload that accepts an execution policy, and the only other substantive change in C++20 is making some overloads of `std::transform` be `constexpr`.  It's a fair bet, since the order in which the operation (`UnaryOperation` or `BinaryOperation`) is applied to elements is unspecified, that any operation  which depends on being called in a particular order will be problematical - including those that have side-effects that affect subsequent calls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Qute from standard:

> 25.2.3  Transform                                  [lib.alg.transform]
>    Requires:
>       op and binary_op shall not have any side effects.

[Side Effect ( wikipedia definition )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))

In your case we have next side effect:

```
Converter c( data );  
c( some_const_value ) != c( some_const_value );
```

You don't have any guarantees for your algorithms, but I belive that it will works on almost all stl implementations.

**Suggested solution**
It seems I know one way to do what you need:
    use boost::counting_iterator - for iterate over two containers;

it will looks like:

```
bool bit_enabled( size_t data, unsigned char number )
{
    return ( data & 1 << number ) != 0;
}

std::string select_word( 
                const std::string& word,
                size_t data, 
                size_t number )
{
    return bit_enabled( data, number ) ? word : std::string( ' ', word.length() );
}

const size_t data = 7;
const boost::array< std::string, 3 > vocabulary = { "a", "b", "c" };
std::vector< std::string > result;
std::transform(
    vocabulary.begin(),
    vocabulary.end(),
    boost::counting_iterator< size_t >(0),
    back_inserter( result ),
    boost::bind( &select_word, _1, data, _2 )
);
```

Also maybe if you will define bit iterator or will use some bit container you will can use boost::zip_iterator for iterate both containers.

**EDIT:**
Yestarday I found [interest article](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403769) which contain definition of Side Effect by standard.

> The Standard defines a side effect as
>   follows: Accessing an object
>   designated by a volatile lvalue,
>   modifying an object, calling a library
>   I/O function, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are
>   all side effects, which are changes in
>   the state of the execution
>   environment.

**EDIT:**
I hope it will be latest edit.
I am always tought that "no have side effect" mean:
f(a) should be equal f(a) always. ( f independed from execution environment: memory/cpu/global variables/member variables as in your case etc).
"Not produce side effect" mean - don't changing execution environment.

But in c++ standard we have more low-level defintion for Side effect.

Thing what you do in your example named as **Stateful** functor.
Standard doesn't say about "Statefull" functors, but also doesn't say about count of copies of your functor - you couldn't use this trick because it is unspecified behavior.

See Standard Library Issues list ( similar issue for predicat ):
http://anubis.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#92

Comment: Thanks for explanation of the "Side effect".

Comment: Nice counting_iterator! Transform can use two containers. Would you change the solution once again?

Comment: i also considered that definition of side-effect. but it does not make any sense in this context. imagine that you do this thing in operator(): { int a; a = 4; return T(t, a); } would be a side effect (modifying the local variable "a") and thus not allowed by the spec of transform.

Comment: in the end, i think it wants to say that it just can't rely on any member/free variables like the article describes.

Comment: Nice boost solution. Good links.

Answer (score 2):

I've just checked the standard and if I understand it correctly the answer is no.  The description of 'transform' has the following additional requirement (25.2.3):

> **Requires**: op and binary_op shall not have any side effects.

Reaching back into the depths of my memory, I remember a talk given [Nicolai Josuttis](http://www.josuttis.com/) at an [ACCU](http://accu.org/) conference, where he showed that for a particular type of container and STL implementation, the function object was copied. [Éric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59781/201ric-malenfant) provided [this](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403769) link to a Dr. Dobb's article that discusses the differences in more detail.

**EDIT:**  Alternative solution:

The *for_each* algorithm does not have this restriction, so you could change your Converter object to take a reference to the result vector and do the push_back inside the Converter function.

```
struct Converter
{
  Converter( std::size_t value, std::vector<std::string> & result ):
      value_( value ), i_( 0 ), result_(result)
  {}
  void operator() ( const std::string& word )
  {
    result_.push_back ( value_ & ( 1 << i_++ ) ) ?
             word:
             std::string( word.size(), ' ' );
  }
  std::size_t value_;
  std::size_t i_;
  std::vector<std::string> & result_;
};
```

And use *for_each* rather than *transform*:

```
std::vector v;
// initialization of v  
std::for_each ( v.begin()
              , v.end(),
              Converter( data, result ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the side effect.

Comment: "In practice I think this can mean..." Where I can find a prove of this?

Comment: Erm....well - I can only claim to know this after I attended an ACCU conference in Oxford where Nicolai Josuttis gave a talk with a real code example.  A quick google search found the following: http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/2007/02/i-was-discussing-about-problem-here.html

Comment: This http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403769 also gives a good overview of the differences between for_each and transform.

Comment: I've passed through links. There is nothing about copy. And who would like to copy functors in their algorithm, I mean what for?

Comment: There is a paragraph which starts with: "One conceivable optimization would be execution of the transformation in parallel threads...".  As you can imagine, each thread would then have its own copy of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of a case where side-effects would be a definite *bad thing*, consider a hypothetical parallel STL implementation which split the work between several CPUs.

I believe this was in the minds of the authors of STL.  The original STL was from SGI, one of the larger names in building massively parallel single-image and cluster systems.

Comment: Interesting guess about "parallel STL". I need some kind of proof. Quote from the standard about copying or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. This is because you feed iterators to your `Converter` object. For a sequence container like `vector` you get `i` to correspond to the order of the elements. However, for associative containers like `map/multimap/set/multiset` this may not be (will most probably not be) valid.

Comment: Algorithm for set still use output iterator to add new items. So it takes one and push one to the output. I doubt about "UnaryOperation shall not have any side effects".

Answer (score -1):

I believe there are some instances where the answer is yes, but there are also definite cases where it's no. Without being able to recall which (sorry), and to make the code less brittle, I would not rely on it and keep i outside the functor to be safe.
ie inside `Converter` do:

`Converter( std::size_t value, std::size_t& i ): value_( value ), i_ ( i ) {}`


and
`std::size_t &i_;`

 then invoke with
`std::vector v;`
`std::size_t i(0);`
`// initialization of v`  
`std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(),
                std::back_inserter( result ), Converter( data, i ) );`

Messy, but safer.

Comment: Updating a variable outside the functor via a reference member in the functor is equally as much of a side effect... As of now, it's not clear to me that the non-execution-policy variants of `transform()` are actually disallowed side effects (in general; _cppreference_ states they must not modify the passed ranges, only) - probably because the old blanket rule was to allow for parallelism, where you can't expect that `i_` would not cause race conditions or at least would be incremented in the expected order... but it is equally vulnerable to such pitfalls whether it's stored inside or outside.